Is it normal for cabinet nominees to meet with senators before hearings?
A number of Trump's nominees for his cabinet have been having private meetings with senators in the past couple of weeks. My memory could be faulty, or maybe it just didn't get much publicity, but I don't remember meetings like this in the past.
Is this normal? Why wouldn't they wait until the confirmation hearings to ask the necessary questions of the candidates? Or conversely, why do they need formal, public hearings if they can interview the candidates privately?
Does this mean that the hearings are mostly for show? Grandstanding is not uncommon during formal hearings.
Is there any information about what goes on during these meetings? Could they help the candidates prepare for the hearings, so they also put on a better show? If they know what kinds of questions they're likely to receive, they'll be better prepared to give the answers the senators want to hear.

Have you ever been to a job interview?  Have you had an "informal chat with the team" before the formal interview process?

@JamesK Plenty of job interviews, can't recall ever having contact with anyone beforehand.

@JamesK Of course, that doesn't include times when I got my foot in the door through existing personal/professional relationships. One time the hiring manager had been my manager at a previous company.

Okay, well, your expericence is different from mine.  In nearly all job interviews I've been involved in, there have been formal elements (demonstration of work, interview) and informal (lunch with the team, tour of the site)

@JamesK I've had that as part of the interview process. E.g. if the interviews cover the whole day, there might be a group lunch in the middle. I thought you meant something informal before the interview.

Have you ever interviewed for a C-suite role in a corporation with at least $5M in yearly revenue? Individual contributors and C-suite interviews work entirely differently.

@JonathanReez Nope. I'm a computer programmer, and I've avoided management positions (or even supervisory roles) like the plague.

Well, there you go. That’s why this is surprising to you.

@JonathanReez I'm not really sure it's fair to consider the confirmation process to be like a job interview. The candidates are mostly well known public figures, often politicians they've worked with in the past. But the reason for my question was because I thought this was what the public hearings were for.

There are tens of thousands of "public figures" out there, its impossible for everyone to know everyone else, no matter how well connected they are. It is absolutely like a job interview for a C-Corp position and that's exactly how it works if you ever get to earning at least $1M/year as an executive. Of course, 99.9% of workers out there will never get anywhere close to these numbers or be a part of any serious vetting process.

@JonathanReez As I said, most of them are politicians that the senators already know. Trump is somewhat unusual in nominating a bunch of TV celebrities rather than career politicians. But RFK Jr is someone who has been known to politicians for some time (he's part of one of the most well known political dynasties).

And consider Gaetz -- he came right out of the current Congress, and he was already the subject of an investigation. Assuming he stayed in the running, what could he tell them in private different from what the house report already found or what he would say in the public hearing?

Even if someone was literally a Senator before, most other Senators would not necessarily know him all that well, especially when it comes to their qualifications/opinions about how a particular institution should run. You're trying to claim that something wrong simply on the basis of never having held a position of power or even considered for one, which is the norm for ~99.9% of people out there.

@JonathanReez I admit that I'm giving politicians the benefit of the doubt that they keep up with the news. Any well-informed person should know who RFK Jr. is by now -- he was a prominent Presidential candidate, after all. OTOH, the guy from Fox News who is tapped to be Sec of Defense deserves plenty of grilling.

Neither you nor I have any idea what JFK Jr. is like in real life, what parts of what he does/says are true vs. what he's faking for drama and clickbait. That's what private meetings are for.

@JonathanReez Or what public hearings are for....

Yes, it is perfectly normal for a any presidential nominee to meet with various senators before the confirmation hearings, this is done for several reasons.

For a senator to get to know a nominee they are not familiar with.
For a senator to get a better understanding of how the nominee will perform in the job similar to a job interview
For the nominee to work on gaining support from the senator
For the nominee to work on explaining how they will do the job

These meetings with senators and the nominee are important as they not only help shape how that senator will vote in the hearings but how they will act in general. Getting the support of some key senators can be critical for gaining the support of others based on how much support those senators show in hearings.

FWIW, there has never been a time in my lifetime (I'm in my 50s) when this has not been normal and the norm.

And just tonight on PBS News Hour one of the reporters also mentioned that it's normal. They were talking about RFK Jr and mentioned that so far he's only met with Republicans, who are presumably already inclined to be on his side.

@Barmar I wouldn't necessarily presume so. Many of Mr Trump's candidates irk even Republicans. Though the goal is probably to have some that are so over the top that the ones "just a mile over the top rather than ten" will we considered sane.

@jcaron I'm not saying that everyone will get a free pass -- Gaetz withdrew his nomination because it was clear he wouldn't be approved. But they're biased in his favor.

@Barmar RFK Jr has had some past issues with various Republicans on many topics, such as vaccines (too anti) and abortion (not anti enough), and may be trying to find a way of smoothing these over before the hearings.

@jcaron But does it really matter if the nominees ‘irk’ them?  We have four years of previous experience that makes it feel more likely that even if some vocally complain, they will still blindly vote for whatever Trump wants.

@suchiuomizu This is becoming an issue because it appears that some of Trumps nominees are not getting Republican support and are being threatened into supporting the picks.


Does this mean that the hearings are mostly for show?

Hearings conducted by the Senate are part of the process of providing  advice and consent to the President for treaties and judicial and cabinet appointments. The entire process normally includes non-public meetings and private, informal discussions, in order that the hearings themselves are operated efficiently, and are not bogged down searching for information.
The role of the Senate to advise and consent is written in the  US Constitution, Article II, Section 2, Clause 2. Note that the rules and procedures governing evaluation of presidential appointments are not in the constitution. Except for the ratio of votes necessary for certain types of bills to pass, all senate rules are written and voted upon by the senate itself, outside the framework of the constitution. Here is the entire text of  Art. II, Sec. 2, Cl. 2, dealing with treaties and appointments:

[The President] shall have Power, by and with the Advice and Consent
of the Senate, to make Treaties, provided two thirds of the Senators
present concur; and he shall nominate, and by and with the Advice and
Consent of the Senate, shall appoint Ambassadors, other public
Ministers and Consuls, Judges of the Supreme Court, and all other
Officers of the United States, whose Appointments are not herein
otherwise provided for, and which shall be established by Law: but the
Congress may by Law vest the Appointment of such inferior Officers, as
they think proper, in the President alone, in the Courts of Law, or in
the Heads of Departments.

(At the time of the Framing of the Constitution, the separation of powers, and especially a weak executive, were seen as necessary to protect against autocratic rule.)
The full Senate and committees operate under the artificial structure of Parliamentary Rules of debate. This structure of orderly procedural debate is not conducive to the ordinary give-and-take of conversational discussion. Therefore, the senate rules provide for the informal, in person, and often private consultations with lobbyists, special interest groups, and appointments by the president to cabinet and federal judiciary positions. It is crucial to understand that both formal parliamentary debate and private, informal, face-to-face meetings are parts of the process necessary for the senate to ultimately vote to give or deny consent.  With presidential appointments, it is a normal part of the process for individual senators and their staffs to meet directly with nominees. This allows for candid discussion in a non-public setting to discuss possible problems with the nominees, and allows senators and staff to examine the nominees' history and expressed points of view. The purpose is not to "coach" the nominees into giving "correct" answers during the hearings, but to gather information and express concerns prior to the public hearings and debate.
The time allocated for public hearings and debate is limited. The highly structured parliamentary rules exist in order to have efficient public hearings. However, the equally important informal, private meetings take place over time not governed by the rules of debate, and allow senators to prepare the questions they plan to ask during hearings and debate.
Since 1789 these public and private procedures have evolved to ensure candid communication, to provide senators with the facts necessary for forming their opinions, and to make the most of the time allotted. Individual meetings with nominees is a regular part of helping to speed the process along.
Since the senate operates both formally and informally there is nothing inherently shady or unfair about private meetings. The end result is to fully vet the nominees and decide on their qualifications. Partisan politics always plays a role, but it is to be expected as this is a political process. A nominee of a Republican president will normally have different private interactions with Democratic and Independent senators than with Republican senators.
The constitution is a framework on which the country's laws are built. It does not contain the minutiae of day to day operation of the three co-equal branches of government. The senate, like all other parts of government, is a self-governing institution. Unless some action is secifically prohibited in the constitution, they make what rules and procedures are deemed necessary for orderly conducting the business of government.

This doesn’t appear to address the question if meeting with senators before the hearing is normal

I'm not asking why senators question the nominees, I know about the "advise and consent" clause. The question is about private meetings versus collective and public hearings.

@Barmar and my answer is that the advise and consent clause does not specify how the senate decides. It doesn't specify what hearings are required or whether there are private meetings. I hope I explained how formal parliamentary procedure and informal face-to-face meetings are how the senate makes its decisions. The senate can't "pass" anything without a vote or unanimous consent, but what goes into deciding how to vote is up to the senate's formal and informal procedures.

@Barmar - The issue of private meetings appears to be addressed by "... with presidential appointments, it is a normal part of the process for individual senators and their staffs to meet informally with nominees. This is in order to privately discuss issues they may wish to explore prior to public debate, ..."
